# How can I regain billing account administrator access if I've already changed the only administrator into normal user?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, account, billing

How could I undo the operation of access changes from `billing account administrator` into `billing account user`?

Answer (score 0):

You can re-grant permission with a user with a higher role on the org, like IAM Security Admin or Organization Admin.

Comment: Cannot do that with the current access

Comment: Then you should find someone who does. You can't use a user with a low role to grant another user a higher role.